# ImportXML XPath advice

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

I'm trying to scrape this webpage:
https://www.nextory.se/bok/heroine-mons-kallentoft-markus-lutteman/9789188345844

I want to scrapte the title, the cover photo, the book description, and the book info in the bottom.

I tried for 2 hours figuring out the correct Xpath formula for Google Sheets...

There is for example the division "single__Book__textcontent" that should give me the text from this div, but cannot get it to work in sheets!

Tried this one without success:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='div.single__Book__textcontent']")
```

Comment: Anyone got any input on this? Thanks so much.

Comment: @Andersson was right about the problem with your XPath: The class attribute you're looking for is `'single__Book__textcontent'`, not `'div.single__Book__textcontent'`. The `div.` looks like you're trying to use a CSS selector in your XPath. I don't know why the XPath didn't work though.

Comment: Maybe if you define "cannot get it to work" / "without success" more specifically, we could help you. What happened when you tried the above `IMPORTXML(...)`? How did the result differ from what you were hoping for?

Comment: Hi Lars, sorry for my late reply, thought this thread was dead. I simply get "resource not found on url" while I know its there... Its very strange. I used importXML before without similar issues pulling data, but without this obstacle.